# Como puedo obtener los datos de una subclave en localstore

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objeto, local-storage

estoy intentando hacer una lista de usuario donde cada uno tenga su propia clave, como se puede observar en la imagen, ahora me veo con el problema de como llamar la clave con sus datos, todo esto es en la localstore

mi propósito es, que al insertar una clave de usuario en un input este arroje todos los datos de ese usuario

```javascript
///datos de usuarios a insertar

const az55E=[
   az5n0={login: "cornelyx1",  nombre:"Yunior A", apellido: "Crornelio", codtrabajo: "A12345678998764321", fotoA:"c"},

   az5n1={login: "cornelyx2",  nombre:"Yunior B", apellido: "Crornelio", codtrabajo: "B12345678998764321", fotoA:"c"},

   az5n2={login: "cornelyx3",  nombre:"Yunior C", apellido: "Crornelio", codtrabajo: "C12345678998764321", fotoA:"c"},

   az5n3={login: "cornelyx4",  nombre:"Yunior D", apellido: "Crornelio", codtrabajo: "D12345678998764321", fotoA:"c"},
]

//insertar en el localStore

localStorage.setItem("az55E",JSON.stringify(az55E));

en el localStore se crea la clave az55E y las siguiente subclaves
>az5n0

>az5n1

>az5n2

>az5n3
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y pon tanto el código como los datos de ejemplo _como texto, con formato_. [No todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976).

Comment: Si por 'clave de usuario' te refieres a az5n0, az5n1, az5n2 etc, entonces lastimosamente esas referencias no se van a guardar en el LS. Deberías pasar ese valor como propiedad de cada objeto usuario, o cambiar la estructura de los datos de usuario para poder acceder facilmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que te parece un diccionario mejor? Se puede acceder mas fácilmente por la clave con la notación de brackets:

```
const az55E={
  az5n0: {login: "cornelyx1",  nombre:"Yunior A", apellido: "Crornelio", codtrabajo: "A12345678998764321", fotoA:"c"},
  az5n1: {login: "cornelyx2",  nombre:"Yunior B", apellido: "Crornelio", codtrabajo: "B12345678998764321", fotoA:"c"},
  az5n2: {login: "cornelyx3",  nombre:"Yunior C", apellido: "Crornelio", codtrabajo: "C12345678998764321", fotoA:"c"},
  az5n3: {login: "cornelyx4",  nombre:"Yunior D", apellido: "Crornelio", codtrabajo: "D12345678998764321", fotoA:"c"},
}

//insertar en el localStore
localStorage.setItem("az55E",JSON.stringify(az55E));
```

Entonces se pueden recuperar y referenciarse a cada usuario individual asi:

```
// recuperar lista de usuarios
let users = localStorage.getItem('az55E')
users = JSON.parse(users)
// recuperando un usuario por su clave
console.log(users['az5n0'])
```

Comment: excelente su sugerencia, me a funcionado mejor de los esperado, muchas gracias